# How can you make snares safe?

Tags: hunting

I've been watching a LOT of snare/trap setting videos.  They spend an lot of time making the snares nigh invisible.  None of these snares would seriously injure a person, but I would like to avoid hurting people with traps.

Is there a way to flag a snare set or trap set so that it warns humans without also warning away the intended game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not exactly a direct answer but may be more appropriate:

I feel that signposting a snare is a good way of getting your game stolen so in general I would advise not signposting but instead making the snare where animals will go but not where humans will walk.

This is a lot easier than it sounds- you can usually spot popular routes for small animals just off the beaten track and set accordingly.